@scheduled annotated methods are overlapping during execution
I have 15 methods that are annotated with @scheduled annotation (in spring boot). In my application.yml file, I have set the spring.task.scheduler.pool.size property as 9.
The task of each of the methods is to retrigger a pipeline in a Gitlab repo i.e., say, method 1 triggers pipeline of branch 1, method 2 triggers pipeline of branch 2, etc, using Gitlab APIs. The thread sleeps until the pipeline execution has completed and then prints some messages.
The annotation on the methods are like this-
@scheduled(fixedRate=50000)
Note: the fixedRate attribute for each method is different.
Problem - I see that more than 1 pipelines of the same branch are triggered at the same time.
i.e., in the gitlab pipeline UI, I see that 2 pipelines for branch 1 are being executed at the same time.
My thoughts - I think that when the fixedRate is less than the method execution time, another thread start's the same method's execution. That's why their executions are getting overlapped.
Could anyone please suggest a fix for this?
My thoughts - I think that when the fixedRate is less than the method execution time, another thread start's the same method's execution. That's why their executions are getting overlapped.

You indicated you print messages after a task completes. Do you see these messages when 2 pipelines are running? If not, then your assumption is correct. You may want to look into using fixedDelay instead of fixedRate. fixedDelay won't trigger concurrent executions of the same task. You want to look at the limitations of using fixedDelay if you are using virtual threads.
